# Can this generator expression be modified to match for loop result?

Tags: python, generator-expression

Consider this for loop:

```
y = []
for z in ('a', 'b\nc', 'd'):
    y.extend(z.splitlines())
```

The flat list `y` is not similarly obtained by

```
y = []
y.extend(z.splitlines() for z in ('a', 'b\nc', 'd'))
```

Can the generator expression be modified to return a flat list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a double loop:

```
y.extend(v for z in ('a', 'b\nc', 'd') for v in z.splitlines())
```

If `y` starts out empty, you may as well make this a list comprehension:

```
y = [v for z in ('a', 'b\nc', 'd') for v in z.splitlines()]
```

You can also use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain

y.extend(chain.from_iterable(z.splitlines() for z in ('a', 'b\nc', 'd')))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> [v for z in ('a', 'b\nc', 'd') for v in z.splitlines()]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> y = []
>>> y.extend(v for z in ('a', 'b\nc', 'd') for v in z.splitlines())
>>> y
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> y = []
>>> y.extend(chain.from_iterable(z.splitlines() for z in ('a', 'b\nc', 'd')))
>>> y
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: I don't even have time to read the question and you've already left an answer!